# Rails with Webrick in dev mode and Thin in prod mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, thin, webrick

I just learned about using Thin web server to serve Rails app in production because it is faster and has concurrency. However, I wonder if I should still use Webrick for dev mode and Thin for production mode.
Should I use Thin for both dev and prod? Is there a way to setup Webrick only for dev?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Running different app servers in different environments is a common task.

Most major servers (Thin, Unicorn, and Puma all work like this) can be swapped in by adding their associated gem to a particular group in your Gemfile.

For example, if you wanted to use Thin in production and WEBrick everywhere else, you would add this line to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'thin', group: :production
```

Now thin will get auto-detected in production, but other environments will fall back to WEBrick (the default)

Personally I always replace WEBrick with Thin in my development and test environments, but it makes little practical difference.

Comment: Well, I am still wondering if there is any technical reason why we keep WEBrick for development.